# Solve Diophantine equation: $2^x=5^y+3$ for non-negative integers $x,y$.

Tags: contest-math, diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

Today my friend asked a question for help:

> Find all solutions of $2^x=5^y+3$ for non-negative integers $x,y$.

It is obvious that the solutions are $(x,y)=(2,0),(3,1),(7,3)$, and I think there is no more solution. However, we can't prove that these are the only solutions. We have already tried to mod many numbers and still get "may" possible solutions other than the $3$ solutions I have written. I have surfed the Net and still can't find solutions. I hope you guys can help my friend solve. Thank you very much!

Comment: How are you sure these are the only solutions? Reduce the equation modulo $2$ and see what happens.

Comment: @Allawonder this problem is a contest math problem. It would not consist of big number solution. Also modulo 2 is no used dude XD

Comment: Looking at it modulo powers of two is not going to help for five generates the subgroup of residue classes of the form $1+4k$ modulo $2^m$, for all $m$. On the other hand, for the same reason the congruence modulo $2^m$ determines $y$ uniquely modulo $2^{m-2}$ (given $x$), but this doesn't really rule out anything. Basically: given $x$ there is a 2-adic $y$ that solves the equation. I would guess looking at it modulo powers of five shows something similar: given $y$ there exists a 5-adic $x$.

Comment: The next likely candidate $$2^{20087}\approx5^{8651}+2^{20087}(\ln2)(5.11\times10^{-5})$$ isn't really very close... the numbers are growing exponentially as $2^x$ but the relative errors tend to only decrease as $1/x$.

Comment: Found in various AoPS forum topics according to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%242%5Ex%3D5%5Ey%2B3%24&p=1)

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio Well, that sounds reasonable enough. True, modding out by $2$ helps nothing. For what it may be worth, note that RHS is always of the form $1000k+628$ when $y>4.$ Also, we must have $x>y$ necessarily.

Comment: @Allowander: The RHS alternates between 1000k+628 and 1000k+128

Comment: Using mod 1000, it can be seen that any additional solutions must be of the form $x=100k+7$.  I'm not sure how to prove that no such solutions exist, but I can't find any others either

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen got it. Big primes involved.

Comment: Not too much modular arithmetic required; show that $x=8u+7$ and $y=4v+3$ for any solution other than the two smallest ones. Then rearranging as in Will Jagy's answer yields
$$128(256^u-1)=125(625^v-1).$$
Reducing mod $257$ and distinguishing cases for $u$ odd and even yields $u=0$ as the only option. (When $u$ is even you will find $v\equiv0\pmod{64}$, then reducing mod $256$ shows that $u=0$.)

Answer (score 4):

We start by changing the letters, plugging in your maximal exponents, and arriving at
$$ 128 (2^x - 1) = 125 (5^y-1)  \; . \;   $$
We ASSUME that both $x,y \geq 1$ and get a contradiction.
The main tasks are factoring $p^n - 1$ and finding the order of a prime for some target $n,$  the minimal $k$ such that $p^k \equiv 1 \pmod k$

So, order_2 of 125 is 100, where we have simply $\varphi(125) = 100.$
Thus $100|x.$

Next
$$ 2^{100} - 1 = 3 \cdot 5^3  \cdot 11   \cdot  31  \cdot  41  \cdot  101  \cdot  251  \cdot  601  \cdot  1801  \cdot  4051  \cdot  8101  \cdot   268501 $$
We need $5^y \equiv 1 \pmod {268501}$
Therefore $125 | y.$
$$    5^{125} - 1    = 2^2   \cdot   11   \cdot   71   \cdot   101   \cdot   251   \cdot   401   \cdot   3597751   \cdot   9384251  \cdot \mbox{BIG}        $$
 We need $2^x \equiv 1 \pmod { 9384251}$
Therefore $125 | x.$ From the beginning, we have had $100 | x.$ Put them together, Chinese Remainder Theorem, and we arrive at
$$ 500 | x $$

And
$$ 2^{500}-1 = (2^{100}-1)(2^{400}+2^{300}+2^{200}+2^{100}+1)$$
where $2^{100}-1$ is a multiple of $5^3$ (above) and the second factor is a multiple of $5$ because $2^{100}=16^{25}\equiv 1\bmod 5$.  Thus $2^{500} - 1$ is a multiple of $5^4.$  We have gotten what we wanted,  as
$ 128 (2^x - 1) = 125 (5^y-1)  \;  \;   $  tells us that $ 125 (5^y-1)$ is divisible by $625.$  In turn, this says that $  (5^y-1)$ is divisible by $5.$ This is impossible with $y \geq 1,$ so that $y = 0,$ contradicting our hypothesis.

---

```
factor with gp-pari 

parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500000
? factor( 2^100 -1)
%1 = 
[     3 1]

[     5 3]

[    11 1]

[    31 1]

[    41 1]

[   101 1]

[   251 1]

[   601 1]

[  1801 1]

[  4051 1]

[  8101 1]

[268501 1]

? factor( 5^125 -1)
%2 = 
[                            2 2]

[                           11 1]

[                           71 1]

[                          101 1]

[                          251 1]

[                          401 1]

[                      3597751 1]

[                      9384251 1]

[                     28707251 1]

[                4032808198751 1]

[              767186663625251 1]

[24687045214139234043375683501 1]

? factor( 2^500 -1)
%3 = 
[                     3 1]

[                     5 4]

[                    11 1]

[                    31 1]

[                    41 1]

[                   101 1]

[                   251 1]

[                   601 1]

[                  1801 1]

[                  4051 1]

[                  7001 1]

[                  8101 1]

[                 28001 1]

[                 96001 1]

[                268501 1]

[               3775501 1]

[             229668251 1]

[          269089806001 1]

[   4710883168879506001 1]

[  47970133603445383501 1][+++]
?
```

---

Comment: We do not need to factor $2^{500}-1$ completely.  Simply render $a^5-1=(a-1)(a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1)$ where $a=2^{100}$.  We already have $a\equiv 1\bmod 5$ for this $a$, forcing the quartic factor to impart the additional factor of $5$ that tumbles the edifice.

Comment: @OscarLanzi that sounds good; consider posting that as an answer, I cant say I have ever looked carefully about what simplifications might be available, better explanations,...

Comment: Instead I edit your answer.

Comment: I like your answer with computation, but is there any way to solve this problem without computation? As it used to calculate factorization of big numbers

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio  You are welcome to find other approaches. As to your complaint, suggest you carefully read the answer by Gyumin Roh at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551324/exponential-diophantine-equation-7y-2-3x After that, some of the early ones (links in the second answer) use small numbers.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone wants to learn what is going on in the solution, here are my earlier examples and the person who discovered the method (answer at the first link):

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551324/exponential-diophantine-equation-7y-2-3x

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941354/elementary-solution-of-exponential-diophantine-equation-2x-3y-7

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941354/elementary-solution-of-exponential-diophantine-equation-2x-3y-7/1942409#1942409

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946621/finding-solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation-7a-3b100/1946810#1946810

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2100780/is-2m-1-ever-a-power-of-3-for-m-3/2100847#2100847

[The diophantine equation $5\times 2^{x-4}=3^y-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858769/the-diophantine-equation-5-times-2x-4-3y-1/2858976#2858976)

[Equation in integers $7^x-3^y=4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220085/equation-in-integers-7x-3y-4/3220132#3220132)

[Solve in $\mathbb N^{2}$ the following equation : $5^{2x}-3\cdot2^{2y}+5^{x}2^{y-1}-2^{y-1}-2\cdot5^{x}+1=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3383436/solve-in-mathbb-n2-the-following-equation-52x-3-cdot22y5x2y/3383501#3383501)

[Solve Diophantine equation: $2^x=5^y+3$ for non-negative integers $x,y$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3493828/solve-diophantine-equation-2x-5y3-for-non-negative-integers-x-y/3494267#3494267)

Comment: Hi Will, have a nice new year! This would be a good (initializing) list for a tag `exponential-diophantine-equations` which I'd liked to exist since long. But the community doesn't like to have bounces to frontpage by editing tags, doesn't it?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I suppose they would not like putting a tag on 25 questions in ten minutes. Should be alright if spread out a bit. Also, a tag needs some explanatory text, indicating some things it is about and some things it is not about. Either one of us can do that.

Comment: Will - just introduced the tag. Tagged 3 questions (the OP and first two of your list)- enough for one day...

Answer (score 0):

From WolframAlpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve++2%5Ex%3D5%5Ey%2B3%29+over+integers) we get

$$x = \frac{\log{5^y + 3}}{\log{2}}\quad\text{for}\quad
 5^y\in\mathbb{Z}\quad\land\quad5^y >=-2$$
The restrictions are overkill but simply indicate $y\in\mathbb{Z}$

Applying this in a spreadsheet for $-15000\le y \le 15000$ we get only $3$ pairs.

$$(2,0)\quad
(3,1)\quad
(7,3)\quad$$