# Diophantine equation power of 7 and 2

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers, exponential-diophantine-equations

$$ 7^x = 2^y \cdot 3 + 1$$

Find all positive $(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}^2$

When I look at this equation $\mod 3$ or $\mod 7$ it does hold - but how can I continue from here?

I know that $7^x -1$ is even so I can write it as: $2k$

$$ 2k = 2^y \cdot 3$$

$2$ does not divide $3$ and the same backwards - so $3 \mid k$ thus $k \in \{3, 6, 9 , \dots \}$ (not including $0$ because then $x=0$ which is not allowed)

Also $2 \mid k$ thus $k \in \{2, 4, 6, 8, \dots \}$

But again, I am stuck with a dead end - I am not sure how to continue from here.. I would appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: $(2,4)$ is **a** solution by inspection.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Also $(1,1)$ but how do I generalize this?

Comment: Clearly, $(1,1)$ is a solution (and there are no other solutions with $y=1$). If $y\geq 2$, we have $7^{x}\equiv 1\pmod 4$. Hence, $x$ is even (why?) and $x=2x_1$. Now we can rewrite our equation as $(7^{x_1}-1)(7^{x_1}+1)=2^y\cdot 3$. Can you end now?

Comment: @richrow Why is $x$ even? I mean - it does work, but if I put $1$ or $3$ etc - the remainder isn't $1$ - is there a way to prove it?

Comment: If $x=2x_1+1$ where $x_1\geq 0$, then $7^{x}=7^{2x_1+1}\equiv (-1)^{2x_1+1}=-1\pmod 4$.

Comment: @richrow Thank you! I tried to continue where you left off at $(7^k -1)(7^k +1) = 2^y \cdot 3$ (I called $x_1$ = $k$ just to make it easier to write) so I know that both of these terms are even ($7^k$ is odd $-1$ or $+1$ and it's even) but I got to a dead end here..

Comment: Stack there is  a fine answer by Michael, about three hours ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x>2$ and $y>4$.

Rewrite our equation in the following form:
$$49(7^{x-2}-1)=48(2^{y-4}-1),$$ which says that $2^{y-4}-1$ is divisible by $49$,

which says that $y-4$ is divisible by $21,$ which says $2^{y-4}-1$ is divisible by $2^{21}-1=49\cdot127\cdot337,$

which gives that $7^{x-2}-1$ is  divisible by $337$,

which says $x-2$ is divisible by $56$ (thanks to dear  Will Jagy).

and from here $7^{x-2}-1$ is divisible by $7^{56}-1=2^6\cdot3\cdot5^2\cdot29\cdot113...,$

which gives $48(2^{y-4}-1)$ is divisible by $64$, which is a contradiction.

Id est, our equation has no natural solutions for $x>2$ and $y>4$.

Can you end it now?

Comment: Thank you, Michael. I hope the others notice this. I did put the url for this in my (home computer) list.

Comment: good, bumped in the active queue, while any 10K can still see my list of links

Comment: @Will Jagy I found a simpler solution and fixed my post.

Comment: Oh, very good. I wrote specific programs in C++ to search for brief (and with small primes, if possible) as command line.  \\ jagy@phobeusjunior \\ ./prime_power_minus_one 7 168  \\

    7^168 - 1    = 2^6 3^2 5^2 13 19 29 43 73 113 181 193 337 409 911 1201 2129 3361 4733 51031 309079 517553  cdot mbox{BIG} \\ 

    7^168 + 1    = 2 17 449 673 121633 169553  cdot mbox{BIG} \\  jagy@phobeusjunior \\ ./order 7 337 \\
337    56 = 2^3 * 7 \\ parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500000 \\
? n = 7^56 - 1 \\
%1 = 211587613802425391637729361787678676290060193600 \\
? n % 337 \\
%2 = 0

Comment: It probably won't change anything much. , but the 337 step says $x-2$  is divisible by 56   \\ prime_power_minus_one 7 56  \\  

    7^56 - 1    = 2^6 3 5^2 29 113 337 911 1201 2129 4733 517553  cdot mbox{BIG}  \\

    7^56 + 1    = 2 17 449 673 169553  cdot mbox{BIG}   \\    YES, you still get your 64 = 2^6  The first one is right as is,  \\ order 2 49  \\
49    21 = 3 * 7

Comment: pari-gp  \\ 
? n = 7^56 - 1  \\
%1 = 211587613802425391637729361787678676290060193600  \\
? factor(n) \\
 
[          2 6]  \\ 

[          3 1] \\ 

[          5 2] \\ 

[         29 1] \\ 

[        113 1] \\ 

[        337 1] \\ 
 
[        911 1] \\

[       1201 1] \\ 

[       2129 1] \\ 

[       4733 1] \\ 

[     517553 1] \\ 

[  515717329 1] \\ 

[13564461457 1] \\ 

?

Comment: @Will Jagy  Yes, you are right. I missed it. I fixed. Thank you!

Comment: @WillJagy Hey Will, I remember that you posted a CW answer with a lot of links for solving diophantine equation similar to this one -  however now it is gone, can you please recover it? It was very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: @Stack I undeleted.

Answer (score 2):

CW answer, votes don't affect me for this one.

There is a very good method for

$$ a p^m = b q^n + c,  $$
where all are positive integers and $p,q$ are prime

discovered by https://math.stackexchange.com/users/292972/gyumin-roh

[Exponential Diophantine equation $7^y + 2 = 3^x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551324/exponential-diophantine-equation-7y-2-3x)

[Elementary solution of exponential Diophantine equation $2^x - 3^y = 7$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941354/elementary-solution-of-exponential-diophantine-equation-2x-3y-7)

[Elementary solution of exponential Diophantine equation $2^x - 3^y = 7$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941354/elementary-solution-of-exponential-diophantine-equation-2x-3y-7/1942409#1942409)  ME!  41, 31, 241, 17

[Finding solutions to the diophantine equation $7^a=3^b+100$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946621/finding-solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation-7a-3b100/1946810#1946810)   343 - 243 =
100

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2100780/is-2m-1-ever-a-power-of-3-for-m-3/2100847#2100847

[The diophantine equation $5\times 2^{x-4}=3^y-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858769/the-diophantine-equation-5-times-2x-4-3y-1/2858976#2858976)

[Equation in integers $7^x-3^y=4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220085/equation-in-integers-7x-3y-4/3220132#3220132)

[Solve in $\mathbb N^{2}$ the following equation : $5^{2x}-3\cdot2^{2y}+5^{x}2^{y-1}-2^{y-1}-2\cdot5^{x}+1=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3383436/solve-in-mathbb-n2-the-following-equation-52x-3-cdot22y5x2y/3383501#3383501)

[Solve Diophantine equation: $2^x=5^y+3$ for non-negative integers $x,y$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3493828/solve-diophantine-equation-2x-5y3-for-non-negative-integers-x-y/3494267#3494267)  128 - 125 = 3

Hello, Sailor

There was a girl in high school, active in "forensics" which was combined debate and related competition among many schools. She had practiced a really excellent Hello, Sailor. At the time, about 1974...

Eric Idle wrote Hello Sailor, his first novel, in 1970

A book of the same title was mentioned by Idle and Cleese in the Monty Python's Flying Circus episode "Sex and Violence" during "The Wrestling Epilogue" sketch, in which a humanist philosophy professor, author of a novel entitled "Hello Sailor," debates an Anglican monsignor over the existence of God in an officiated wrestling match.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello,_sailor

should bump question in active queue ... appears MIchael's answer does appear first maybe for being accepted .. Seems appropriate  ... compare active queue  after deleting

Comment: Why did you post it? I wanted to show, how it works here. :)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg You are always welcome to ;)   

Thanks for the posts I will dig into them now!

Answer (score 1):

I edit my previous answer. My only purpose here is to give an answer distinct from that given by the distinguished friend Michael Rozenberg.

We easily verify that $y=1$ and $y=4$ give two solutions and that $y=2$ and $y=3$ must be discarded; also $x$ must be even (reducing modulo $16$) so we consider the new equation
$$7^{2x}=3\cdot2^{4+y}+1\iff(49)^x=48\cdot2^y+1;\space x\ge1, \space y\ge1$$
Now if $x$ is even then $$1\equiv8\cdot2^y+1\pmod{10}\Rightarrow 0\equiv2^{y+3}\pmod{10}$$ which is not possible so $x$ should be odd.

On the other hand we have $$(48+1)^x=48^2M+48x+1=48\cdot2^y+1\Rightarrow48M+x=2^y$$ and $x$ should be even.

Since $x$ cannot be odd and even,the only solutions of the proposed equation are $(x,y)=(1,1),(2,4)$

Comment: Are you saying $(48+1)^x-1=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{x-1}48^{x-k}$ and that's odd?!

Comment: I see now your comment. Thank you.What I was said is $$\sum_{k=0}^{x-1}48^{x-k}=48\cdot2^y$$ after eliminating $1$ in both sides.