# Find all solutions to the diophantine equation $7^x=3^y+4$ in positive integers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all solutions to the diophantine  equation $7^x=3^y+4$ in positive integers.
> I couldn't have much progress.

Clearly $(x,y)=(1,1)$ is a solution. And there's no solution for $y=2$.

Assume $y \ge 3$ and $x \ge 1$.

By $\mod 9$, we get $7^x \equiv 4\mod 9 \implies x \equiv 2 \mod 3 $.

By $\mod 7$,we get $y \equiv 1 \mod 6$.

I also tried $\mod 2$ but it didn't work.

Please post hints ( not a solution). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, one easily eliminated case:  if $x=2k$ were even then $7^{2k}-4=(7^k-2)(7^k+2)$ so...

Comment: General remark:  since there is a solution, namely $(1,1)$, congruences alone won't get it done, though of course you can use congruences to eliminate a lot of cases.

Comment: @lulu there is a method that usually wors with small numbers http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941354/elementary-solution-of-exponential-diophantine-equation-2x-3y-7/1942409#1942409   and many others

Comment: @SunainaPati FYI, your equation is $7^x - 3^y = 4$. For $x, y \gt 1$, the table in the [Generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture#Generalization) section of Wikipedia's "Catalan's conjecture" article shows for a difference of $4$, there are *only* $3$ solutions with perfect powers less than $10^{18}$. These are $8 - 4 = 2^3 - 2^2$, $36 - 32 = 6^2 - 2^5$ and $125 - 121 = 5^3 - 11^2$. Thus, there's no solution for powers of $7$ and $3$ within that range, implying (but not proving) there are no other solutions than the $(1,1)$ one you've already found.

Comment: @WillJagy  Ah, thank you.  I have seen such things before, and was trying to reconstruct the method.  Glad to have the reference.

Comment: @SunainaPata Also note later in that article, Pillai's conjecture states "... each positive integer occurs only finitely many times as a difference of perfect powers ...".

Comment: @lulu  I have a file of url's at home, pasted a bunch of examples into a CW answer

Comment: @JohnOmielan there is a successful method, see links in my CW answer

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for your feedback. I was just reading your [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3220132/602049) for this specific equation when you commented.

Comment: @JohnOmielan good point, I was not sure I did this particular one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's $3(3^a-1)=7(7^b-1)$ with $a=x-1$ and $b=y-1$.

Therefore $7\mid3^a-1$, so $a$ is a multiple of (what?).

> Therefore, $3^a-1$ is a multiple of $13$.

> Therefore, $7^b-1$ is a multiple of $13$.

> Therefore, $b$ is a multiple of (what?).

> Therefore, $7^b-1$ is a multiple of $9$.

> Therefore, $3(3^a-1)$ is a multiple of $9$.

> Therefore, $a$ is (what?).

> Therefore, $x$ is (what?).

Comment: Yes!! I got it :) Thankyou !!!!

Answer (score 5):

examples to study

CW:Catalan Thue Ramanujan Nagell Tijdeman p^x - q^y = C

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/292972/gyumin-roh

[Exponential Diophantine equation $7^y + 2 = 3^x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551324/exponential-diophantine-equation-7y-2-3x)

[Elementary solution of exponential Diophantine equation $2^x - 3^y = 7$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941354/elementary-solution-of-exponential-diophantine-equation-2x-3y-7)

[Elementary solution of exponential Diophantine equation $2^x - 3^y = 7$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941354/elementary-solution-of-exponential-diophantine-equation-2x-3y-7/1942409#1942409)  ME!  41, 31, 241, 17

[Finding solutions to the diophantine equation $7^a=3^b+100$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946621/finding-solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation-7a-3b100/1946810#1946810)   343 - 243 =
100

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2100780/is-2m-1-ever-a-power-of-3-for-m-3/2100847#2100847

[The diophantine equation $5\times 2^{x-4}=3^y-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858769/the-diophantine-equation-5-times-2x-4-3y-1/2858976#2858976)

[Equation in integers $7^x-3^y=4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220085/equation-in-integers-7x-3y-4/3220132#3220132)

[Solve in $\mathbb N^{2}$ the following equation : $5^{2x}-3\cdot2^{2y}+5^{x}2^{y-1}-2^{y-1}-2\cdot5^{x}+1=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3383436/solve-in-mathbb-n2-the-following-equation-52x-3-cdot22y5x2y/3383501#3383501)

[Solve Diophantine equation: $2^x=5^y+3$ for non-negative integers $x,y$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3493828/solve-diophantine-equation-2x-5y3-for-non-negative-integers-x-y/3494267#3494267)  128 - 125 = 3

[Diophantine equation power of 7 and 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3818669/diophantine-equation-power-of-7-and-2/3818694#3818694)

[Find natural numbers a,b such that $|3^a-2^b|=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3873689/find-natural-numbers-a-b-such-that-3a-2b-1)  did +-1

Comment: Thank you !!! Those link are really helpful :)